Should all data coming from database be forced through entities to enforce business rules?
I have a DDD backend with heavy use of the repository pattern for getting and saving aggregate roots.
Awhile ago I made the decision to separate querying from my repositories and only use repositories/aggregates when I'm actually modifying data or needing business logic. This allows queries to fetch specific data efficiency and return DTOs.
However, I just stumbled upon an issue with this. One of my aggregate roots (PatientForm) has some business logic which requires signature fields to always be required.
  protected _id: string
  private _name: string
  private _type: FormFieldType
  private _options: FormFieldOption[]
  private _required: boolean

  constructor(data: FormFieldData) {
    super(data)

    this._id = data.id
    this._name = data.name
    this._type = data.type
    this._options = data.options.map(option => new FormFieldOption(option))

    if (data.type === 'SIGNATURE') {
      this._required = true
    } else {
      this._required = data.required
    }
  }

This works fine if all my data runs through the entity (from the repository). However, I have a GetPatientFormQuery which returns the required field straight from the FormField table. This bypasses the business logic of always forcing signature FormFields to be required.
The solution could be to duplicate this same required logic into the query, but that violates the DRY principle. The other solution is to use the aggregate roots instead of a query, but I was hoping to keep query logic separate.
Here's the query for reference. It just pulls data from the database and maps to the DTO.
export class GetPatientFormQuery implements IGetPatientFormQuery {
  constructor(protected prisma: PrismaClient) {}

  async run(params: GetPatientFormParams): Promise<PatientFormDTO | null> {
    if (!params.practiceId) throw new Error('Missing practiceId') // Extra check for safety

    const { patientFormId, practiceId } = params

    // Fetch data
    const data = await this.prisma.patientForm.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: patientFormId,
        practiceId,
      },
      include: {
        responses: {
          include: {
            formField: true,
            stringArrayValue: true,
          },
        },
        form: {
          include: {
            fields: {
              include: {
                options: {
                  orderBy: {
                    order: 'asc',
                  },
                },
              },
              orderBy: {
                order: 'asc',
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    })

    if (!data) return null

    const responses: FormResponseDTO[] = data.responses.reduce((acc: FormResponseDTO[], response) => {
      if (isPatientResponseFormFieldType(response.formField.type)) {
        const value = patientResponseFormFieldValueExtractor[response.formField.type](response)

        const res: FormResponseDTO = {
          id: response.id,
          formFieldId: response.formFieldId,
          value,
        }

        acc.push(res)
      }
      return acc
    }, [])

    // Map data to DTO
    return {
      id: data.id,
      formId: data.formId,
      patientId: data.patientId,
      submitted: data.submitted,
      responses,
      form: data.form,
      updatedAt: data.updatedAt,
    }
  }
}


To answer the header of your question, I say yes. We build domain entities to give them a logic that resembles the business rules of the domain itself. That means, you don't know about repositories, just about entities. Thry could be merged together (domain entities = repository entities) but it's an implementation detail, not a rule.
On the other side, we have also CQRS (command query responsibility segregation) where we use queries and relative dtos to read and repositories and relative entities to write.
Here you have sometimes similar. But, your dto misses some information that only the domain could determine. The optimal solution for this is to move the whole logic about the signature (required or not) in an external service. Then you call it in the entity constructor to decide about the required field or not, and you do the same in your dto. How you implement it is a detail (it could be a simple static function or a whole service that you pass as an argument), the important thing is that you can call without problems from all the places where this business rule should be used.
The advantage is that if the logic changes, you   just update it and all the users will work with the new version.
